# Extract FPS from tcprobe text using Regex

Tags: regex

I have the following info being returned when I run tcprobe -i on a video file:

```
[tcprobe] RIFF data, AVI video
[avilib] V: 30.000 fps, codec=MJPG, frames=1599, width=640, height=480
[avilib] A: 8000 Hz, format=0x01, bits=8, channels=1, bitrate=64 kbps,
[avilib]    54 chunks, 427248 bytes, CBR
[tcprobe] summary for PICT1120.AVI, (*) = not default, 0 = not detected
import frame size: -g 640x480 [720x576] (*)
       frame rate: -f 30.000 [25.000] frc=0 (*)
      audio track: -a 0 [0] -e 8000,8,1 [48000,16,2] -n 0x1 [0x2000] (*)
                   bitrate=64 kbps
           length: 1599 frames, frame_time=33 msec, duration=0:00:53.299
```

I would like to use regex to extract the frame rate (on line 2) please can anyone advise on how I can do this (just the no of frames, and not any of the surrounding text).

PS. Please bare in mind that the fps will vary as I will be using this script on various different video files.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an expression like:

```
([\d.]+) fps
```

With the FPS being in the first capturing group.

Perl example:

```
perl -nE '/([\d.]+) fps/ && say $1'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response all most perfect but would like to lose fps at the end off possible as well?

Comment: @Dino, you don't say what regex flavor/tool you are using, but if it support lookaheads you can use `[\d.]+(?= fps)`. But using the value of the capturing group is preferable (look up how to do that in your tool).

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Sorry my regxex is extremely poor def. need to et round to understanding that a to better!

Answer (score 0):

For just the frames you could use:

```
frames=(\d+)
```

If you want the fps this will work:

```
(\d+.\d+)\sfps
```